# Similarity of Eigendecomposition and SVD

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to intuitively understand the similarity between SVD and eigendecomposition.

I have understand some idea about SVD and eigendecomposition and their differences, but I am curious what is the similarity between them?

Answer (score 1):

SVD work for any complex matrix, not necessarily a square matrix. It says that a linear map between two unitary spaces can be presented, under suitable choices of orthonormal bases, by a matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \Sigma & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\Sigma = \mathrm{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_r)$, $r$ being the rank. This should better be compared with the "canonical form" of a matrix under "equivalence" ($PAQ^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$). In the latter, slightly easier theory, there is no unitary constraints on choosing bases.

By contrast, "eigendecomposition" only works for square matrices, and not all of them. In general, a square matrix cannot be diagonalized. In terms of linear maps, the theory of "eigendecomposition" deals with a linear map from a vector space to itself. Once a basis of the domain is fixed, you have to use it for the target. Whence the matrix representation are related by $A'=PAP^{-1}$.

Nevertheless, there is a relation between eigenvalues and singular values of a square matrix:
\begin{align*}
  |\lambda_1| &\leq \sigma_1 \\
  |\lambda_1 \lambda_2| &\leq \sigma_1\sigma_2 \\
  &\vdots
\end{align*}
where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of the square matrix,
ordered so $|\lambda_1| \geq |\lambda_2|$,
and $\sigma_i$ are the singular values, ordered by
$\sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq \cdots$. Also, the absolute value of $\lambda_1$ can be calculated via a limit (recall that the largest singular value is the operator norm of a matrix):
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sigma_1(A^n).
$$